# Value formula in vlookup

Tags: vlookup

I have an excel file with several tabs, one of them is designed for reporting only. On that tab I want to get information from a different tab using vba code, I can do a vlookup on the page and it works, but I want to to this on vba code.

The problem is that if I do the vlookup I get no results, but if I add a VALUE() formula to the item I will search I do get results.

```
=VLOOKUP(VALUE(XEZ1048317),Table3[#All],4,0)
```

I have tried to do the same on vba but just can't get it to work, data to be searched is a date, so I thought it could be an issue with date storing hour and several things I've read but if I convert cells to number both are the same so it should find information. I have even tried pasting the information on a different cell to make sure formulas do not interfiere, Code looks a bit like this, any help will be really appreciated:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Daily
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B8:D8")) Is Nothing Then

    Range("F8:F12").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("XEZ1048317").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Target.Select
    Range("G8").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("XEZ1048317"), Sheets("IPCM Call Center Stats").Range("Table3"), 4, False)

End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```